# SQL Product Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, matrix

Suppose I sell t-shirts and I have a table where I'm pulling the color and quantity sold and customer, and i wanted to create a matrix with 100 colors on x and y axis, so I can determine what color the customer purchases on their first order and what color they come back to purchase on their second order.

How could I create a matrix without writing out 1000 case when statements?

First Purchase Table

```
|Customer|Color|PurchaseQty|
----------------------------
|   1    |Blue |     2     |
|   2    |Red  |     1     |
|   3    |White|     2     |
---------------------------
```

Second Purchase Table

```
|Customer|Color|PurchaseQty|
----------------------------
|   1    |Red  |     1     |
|   2    |White|     3     |
|   3    |Blue |     1     |
---------------------------
```

```
       Red        White        Blue
--------------------------------------
Red  |              1
--------------------------------------
White|                           1
--------------------------------------
Blue |  1
--------------------------------------
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL532.png)

Comment: What is the logic for Red - White is 1?

Comment: If the y-axis is the First Purchase and the x-axis is the Second Purchase, 1 customer bought Red in their First Purchase (regardless of Qty) and White in their Second Purchase (regardless of Qty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested.  I added a few records to illustrate the distribution

**Sample Data First**

```
Customer    Color   PurchaseQty
1           Blue    2
3           White   2
2           Red     1
4           Red     1      -- < Added
5           Red     1      -- < Added
```

**Sample Data Second**

```
Customer    Color   PurchaseQty
1           Red     1
3           Blue    1
2           White   3
4           Red     1      -- < Added
5           Blue    1      -- < Added
```

**Query**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Color) From #Second  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [YAxis] as [Color],Y1Axis as [Customers],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select YAxis = A.Color
              ,XAxis = B.Color
              ,Y1Axis= count(A.Customer) over (Partition By A.Color)
              ,Value = 1.0/count(*) over(Partition by A.Color)
         From  #First A
         Join  #Second B on (A.Customer=B.Customer)
     ) A
 Pivot (sum(Value) For [XAxis] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns -- Comparitive Size**

[image]

**For a Common Size**

Just set the Value to ...  `,Value = 1.0/count(*) over()`  ...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Many examples of Dynamic Pivots, but here is one which will handle your X/Y matrix

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Color) From #Second  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [YAxis] as [Color],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select YAxis = A.Color
              ,XAxis = B.Color
              ,Value = 1
         From  #First A
         Join  #Second B on (A.Customer=B.Customer)
     ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [XAxis] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
Color   Blue    Red     White
Blue    NULL    1       NULL
Red     NULL    NULL    1
White   1       NULL    NULL
```

Comment: This seems to be working great, if I wanted to get the percentage of customers (33% that bought red came back and bout white), would I divide by the customer count in the pivot? or in the From statement?

Comment: @Ally In the sample data, would it be 100% who purchased red came back an purchased white ?

Comment: hi there again! so I'm trying to rework this SQL to utilize for an attach rate; I'm trying to work through it but was hoping you could help me wrap my head around how to distinguish between the product in the Y axis and the attached in the X...maybe this is the wrong layout? problem is i have about 64 'categories' i'm working with...

Comment: @Ally Not sure what you mean by "attached rate".    In the above answers #Second  is the Y Axis and  #First is the X Axis.  The VALUE is 1 for the count  ...  comparative size is 1/count of color   .... common size is 1 / count of all colors.   The number of products should not be an issue.  Perhaps a new or edited question with sample data and desired results.